# load specific directive from angularjs module using webpack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I'm currently refactoring my angularjs application in order to use webpack and lazyloading.

I would like to **load only one directive from an angularjs module**, instead of loading the whole module to **prevent unused code in my generate bundle**.

Is it possible, **with minor changes**?

Something like

```
import {MyDirective} from './my-module.js';
```

Comment: you can export the directive function definition and use it on another module if this is what you are asking

Comment: you're right but that means I have to modify the code in each directive to make it "exportable". I don't want to modify existing code. I'm asking if there is a way to export only a part of the whole module. - By adding new code in a third part file for example

Comment: well to use something like this on another file "import MyModule from './my-module.js';" i guess you have to at least export only the directive function first . Cant think of a way to pick a module without exporting it first

Comment: I'm exporting the module but not the directive. I want to know if it's possible to do something like: "import {MyDirective} from './my-module.js';"

Comment: Is this for AngularJS(1.x) of Angular(2.x,4.x,5.x) ??

Comment: angularJS (1.x)

Comment: depending on which version of webpack you are using, [Tree Shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/)

Comment: The last version of webpack (4.8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that you are using es6/es2015 syntax(babel/ts-node). Your module has to export method than you can consume it like import.
Using export syntax:

```
// My module 
export { cube, foo, graph };
// Importing
import {cube } from './mymodule'
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

However, exporting directive like this is though. You need to create a directive function and reuse that function in the module and export same time. See below give example

```
// Directive function
angular.module([]).directive('myCustomer', MyCustomDirective);

function MyCustomDirective() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      customerInfo: '=info'
    },
    template: '<template>something here</template>'
  };
}

export {MyCustomDirective}
```

Comment: I accept your answer, because it seems there's nothing else to do. But if you take a look at my question you will see that I already know how to import the directive. I asked with minor changes (= no needs to export it and modfy all my directives). Thank you anyway, maybe I wasn't clear enough